# qunit tests run with grunts grunt-contrib-qunit fails outside of default test folder

Tags: gruntjs, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

The only place I can get qunit tests to run is if the html and js file lives inside the grunt-contrib-qunit\test folder following this information at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit

Anything outside of that test folder, like having a "tests" folder as part of the project root, doesn't work.

Running in debug mode (grunt qunit:defaultTests --debug)
phantomJS will timeout and I can see that "onResourceRequested" doesn't include the qunit css or js files, or the js file test, it only reports on the html file.

Can someone please walk me through how they set this up without using the contrib-qunit\test folder or what changes need to be made as I can only run the the files in that folder.

Comment: Show us your Gruntfile for trying to run tests from a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what do you mean by "outside of test folder", but here's some tips:

- use npm module `connect` to server sources for unit tests, then we can setup any folders to be in your application easily
- check example I created for my rewrite of grunt-contrib-qunit - https://github.com/CrocInc/grunt-croc-qunit/tree/master/example/grunt-croc-qunit-sample , it has Gruntfile with runnable test task. See readme on https://github.com/CrocInc/grunt-croc-qunit/ on motivation for creating the plugin